# How to change table/indexes structure for a query with two aggregated columns?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.1

Do you have any suggestion on how to improve a table structure or its indexes in order to have a single query run faster?

The table has this structure:

```
    docid          | character varying(17) | not null
    seqnr          | numeric               | not null default 1
    creatinguser   | character varying(50) | not null
    creatingdate   | date                  | 
    lastchangeuser | character varying(50) | not null
    lastchangedate | date                  | 
    description    | character varying(50) |
```

Indexes:

```
    "systemdatabydocument_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (docid, seqnr)
    "sdbdchanged" btree (lastchangedate)
    "sdbdcreated" btree (creatingdate)
```

My query (please note that the value in `WHERE` changes) is:

```
SELECT MAX(creatingDate), MAX(lastChangeDate)
FROM agenzia.SystemDataByDocument
WHERE docId = 'Sedi';
```

and explain analyze on a old/slow system with about 250k records on postgresql 8.3.17 is:

```
 Result  (cost=99.05..99.06 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=573.767..573.768 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..39.81 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=280.417..280.418 rows=1 loops=1)
       ->  Index Scan Backward using sdbdcreated on systemdatabydocument  (cost=0.00..22887.95 rows=575 width=8) (actual time=280.414..280.414 rows=1 loops=1)
             Filter: ((creatingdate IS NOT NULL) AND ((docid)::text = 'Sedi'::text))
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..59.24 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=293.332..293.333 rows=1 loops=1)
       ->  Index Scan Backward using sdbdchanged on systemdatabydocument  (cost=0.00..34064.51 rows=575 width=8) (actual time=293.328..293.328 rows=1 loops=1)
             Filter: ((lastchangedate IS NOT NULL) AND ((docid)::text = 'Sedi'::text))
 Total runtime: 573.837 ms
```

while the same plan on postgresql 9.1.11 (on a new/faster machine with about 500k records) is almost the same:

```
 Result  (cost=117.40..117.41 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=537.812..537.813 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..59.73 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=279.532..279.532 rows=0 loops=1)
       ->  Index Scan Backward using sdbdcreated on systemdatabydocument  (cost=0.00..30342.46 rows=508 width=4) (actual time=279.525..279.525 rows=0 loops=1)
             Index Cond: (creatingdate IS NOT NULL)
             Filter: ((docid)::text = 'Sedi'::text)
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..57.67 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=258.270..258.270 rows=0 loops=1)
       ->  Index Scan Backward using sdbdchanged on systemdatabydocument  (cost=0.00..29296.76 rows=508 width=4) (actual time=258.267..258.267 rows=0 loops=1)
             Index Cond: (lastchangedate IS NOT NULL)
             Filter: ((docid)::text = 'Sedi'::text)
 Total runtime: 537.924 ms
```

Thank you very much.

Addendum 1: adding an index with all fields does not help:

```
=>create index testtesttest3 on agenzia.systemdatabydocument (docid,creatingDate,lastChangeDate);
CREATE INDEX
Tempo: 2180,780 ms
=> explain analyze SELECT MAX(creatingDate), MAX(lastChangeDate) FROM agenzia.SystemDataByDocument WHERE docId = 'Sedi';
                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=62.92..62.93 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=281.283..281.284 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..3.68 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.160..0.161 rows=1 loops=1)
       ->  Index Scan Backward using testtesttest3 on systemdatabydocument  (cost=0.00..2118.04 rows=575 width=8) (actual time=0.157..0.157 rows=1 loops=1)
             Index Cond: ((docid)::text = 'Sedi'::text)
             Filter: (creatingdate IS NOT NULL)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..59.24 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=281.109..281.110 rows=1 loops=1)
       ->  Index Scan Backward using sdbdchanged on systemdatabydocument  (cost=0.00..34063.25 rows=575 width=8) (actual time=281.106..281.106 rows=1 loops=1)
             Filter: ((lastchangedate IS NOT NULL) AND ((docid)::text = 'Sedi'::text))
 Total runtime: 281.365 ms
(10 rows)
```

Comment: I think a composite `index(docid,creatingDate,lastChangeDate)` would help

Comment: Why is `seqnr` a `numeric`, not an `integer`?  Also, the 50 char length limit seems to be some arbitrary limit which could be completely omitted.  Furthermore, I would use some underscores to render column names a bit more readable.  I see these do not help with query performance, for that see @Mihai's comment :)

Comment: @Mihai, your suggestion does not work since even with that new index, the plan does not change.

Comment: @dezso, your comment about the table structure is sadly not acceptable since this schema is used across many different DBMS. Let's say this is the schema that works everywhere (informix, oracle, sql-server, mysql, postgresql). About these limits (like 50 chars in length), they are required by the application.

Comment: But i see in your explain that the time was cut in half.

Comment: @Mihai, you are right and I didn't check the plan details. The new index is used in the first part of plan!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Mihai, adding an index that include `docid` as first column help. The best solution is to create two of them, one for `(docid,creatingDate)` and the second one for `(docid,lastChangeDate)`. Please note for simplyfing the index scan, the second fild is ordered `DESCENDING`, infact the first two indexes are ignored. The new plan is now:

```
=# create index testtesttest1 on agenzia.systemdatabydocument (docid,creatingDate);
CREATE INDEX
=# create index testtesttest2 on agenzia.systemdatabydocument (docid,lastChangeDate);
CREATE INDEX
=# create index testtesttest3 on agenzia.systemdatabydocument (docid,creatingDate DESC);
CREATE INDEX
=# create index testtesttest4 on agenzia.systemdatabydocument (docid,lastChangeDate DESC);
CREATE INDEX
=# explain analyze SELECT MAX(creatingDate), MAX(lastChangeDate) FROM agenzia.SystemDataByDocument WHERE docId = 'Sedi';
                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=5.40..5.41 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.151..0.151 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..2.70 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.091..0.091 rows=0 loops=1)
       ->  Index Scan using testtesttest3 on systemdatabydocument  (cost=0.00..1372.58 rows=508 width=4) (actual time=0.085..0.085 rows=0 loops=1)
             Index Cond: (((docid)::text = 'Sedi'::text) AND (creatingdate IS NOT NULL))
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..2.70 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.054..0.054 rows=0 loops=1)
       ->  Index Scan using testtesttest4 on systemdatabydocument  (cost=0.00..1372.58 rows=508 width=4) (actual time=0.053..0.053 rows=0 loops=1)
             Index Cond: (((docid)::text = 'Sedi'::text) AND (lastchangedate IS NOT NULL))
 Total runtime: 0.256 ms
```

Comment: Just curious,could somebody in the know explain why 2 separate indexes `(docid,creatingDate)`,`(docid,lastChangeDate)` work much better than `(docid,creatingDate,lastChangeDate)`?

Comment: @Mihai because that (triple) index would be useful if you wanted to get the `MAX(lastChangeDate)` for every `docid - creatingDate` combination or for a specific `docid` - `creatingDate` combination. But the query is for a specific `docid` only. So with the triple index, it has to go through (index scan) all the tree (below the `docid='Sedi'` value).

Comment: @Mihai, I believe the index is ordered on these colums, so the max(third columns) is not directly accessible in the index and it require a scan. The two different indexes solve the problem

Comment: I just added the reverse order for second field in index, so that MAX function just get the first record indexed.

Comment: I think that Postgres can retrieve both MAX and MIN efficiently, no matter if the column has `ASC` or `DESC` in the index.

Comment: @ypercube You're right! In fact, in my testing on PG 9.3.2 the ordinary index was faster by about 25%...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce these findings on PG 9.3.1 on SQL Fiddle: there they were very similar in speed.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I still have to try with 9, but on 8.3 it was faster with `DESC`.

Comment: I can't determine in which version of PG backward index scanning could be used for aggregates, but I've found some indication that backward index scanning was already in PG 8.1 I only learned of this today too and I may even continue making the indexes `DESC` to make it clearer that that is what is intended.

Comment: @ypercube as shown in the answer, having created both indexes with ASC and DESC, Postgresql selected the DESC ones, so I assume it is the best/fastest index.

Comment: Why do you assume and you don't test with both (forcing use of one or by having only one available)? I mean, it could be faster with the `DESC` index but it well be that the two have same efficiency and Postgres chooses one of them randomly.

Comment: @ypercube I just checked, as you suggested, and they give the exact same timing. Plan show and "Index Scan" when using the `DESC` ordered index, or a "Index Scan Backward" when using an `ASC` ordered index.

Answer (score 1):

1. In general, for many DBMSes to solve the function `MAX(x)` using an index, a *descending* order index on `x` is needed: this index has the property that the MAX value of x is the first value in the index.

   PostgreSQL supports a "backwards index scan" which, as its name suggests, scans the index in reverse order, so that the MAX value is the first value it finds in an index in normal (ascending) order.
2. Then to find the MAX(x) for a key value, eg `select MAX(x) from mytable where id = 27` will require a composite index:

   - the first column needs to be `id` so that the data for the given `id` can be 
     found quickly
   - the second column should be `x descending` so that the first value of the next level of the index is the MAX value of x (or in PostgreSQL, in "normal"/ascending order).
3. To find multiple max values in one query, one needs to create multiple indexes:

   - compound indexes are useful when one is specifying more conditions in the where clause, eg `col1 = 27, col2 = 'black'`, while
   - multiple indexes are useful when retrieving multiple *columns* or *expressions* for the same where clause. In this case you enable the DBMS to perform two index scans and combine the results.

Putting all the above together, you should define two indexes:

```
create index on agenzia.SystemDataByDocument(docId, creatingDate desc);
```

and

```
create index on agenzia.SystemDataByDocument(docId, lastChangeDate desc);
```

In PostgreSQL the second columns of these index could be stored in "normal"/ascending order.